# SPARQL Query to extract subject predicate and object for persons

Tags: rdf, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm new to semantic web and trying to figure out a way to get some data about persons in the format as it is presented in attached image. If anybody could help i'll be thankful.
[image: Subject Prediate Object]

Answer (score 2):

As you're starting out, I'm going to make a few assumptions. Firstly, that image is an over-simplification of the data that will be returned, all of the subjects and predicates will be URI's and not all that data is in DBpedia.

I'm going to assume you will be using the [SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) at  , which will return results to you, in browser in a HTML table. You can also send SPARQL requests to the same URL with appropriate software/libraries.

Here's a query to get you started, there's an awful lot of people on DBpedia, so I've made it so you can choose who you want. The query will also only return ?objects that are in English, you can remove the `&& lang(?object) = "en"` to get all objects. The line `?subject a dbo:Person.` is not strictly required, but I've left it in so that you can remove all filtering and still only get people. `LIMIT 20` is the maximum number of rows it will return.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE {
   ?subject a dbo:Person.
   ?subject ?predicate ?object.
   FILTER (?subject IN (dbr:John_Lennon, dbr:Yoko_Ono, dbr:Jimmy_Carter,
           dbr:Bill_Clinton) && lang(?object) = "en")
} LIMIT 20
```

Put that into the form [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) and you'll get some results as a table with three columns : `?subject, ?predicate, ?object`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. yes i'm new and i'm using apche jena in eclipse. i just need data in this format because for my semster project i have to do some assoiciation rule mining over this rdf data.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 supports inline data via [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) . language filtering can be done via disjunction `||` on the filter predicates, e.g. either URI or English literal: `SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?predicate ?object
{
VALUES ?subject {dbr:John_Lennon 
                     dbr:Yoko_Ono
                     dbr:Jimmy_Carter
                     dbr:Bill_Clinton}

?subject ?predicate ?object
FILTER (isURI(?object) || langmatches(lang(?object), "en"))
}`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try wikidata and the command line tool
https://github.com/maxlath/wikibase-cli

```
npm install -g wikibase-cli
```

Then configure your language to english

```
wd config lang en
```

now search your subjects one by one:

```
wd search "John Lennon"
```

and pick/deduplicate the entry you are looking for e.g. for John Lennon:

```
Q1203      John Lennon English singer and songwriter, founding member of The Beatles (1940–1980)
```

check that there is a claim for your predicate e.g.

```
wd claims Q1203 | grep instrument
instrument (P1303):    
   guitar (Q6607) | 
   piano (Q5994) | 
   harmonica (Q51290) | 
   bass guitar (Q46185) | 
   keyboard instrument (Q52954) | 
   voice (Q17172850)
```

repeat ...

If you are not sure about the available predicates use

```
wd props
```